# Выписать историзмы и архаизмы

Tags: лексика

Помогите, пожалуйста, в чём ошибка?

> Выпишите из предложений архаизмы и историзмы (в той форме, что и в тексте):
>
> 1) В прежние времена он давал девицам уроки игры на клавикордах;
>   2) Городничий жаден, за грош удавится, сызнова барщину завел;
>   3) Здесь полковой цирюльник бреет унтер-офицеров;
>   4) Погасло дневное светило, на море синее вечерний пал туман. Шуми, шуми, послушное ветрило, волнуйся подо мной, угрюмый океан!

архаизмы: девицам, сызнова, цирюльник, светило, ветрило

историзмы: клавикордах, городничий, грош, барщину, унтер-офицеров.

Comment: А почему мимо-то?  "Цирюльник", конечно, больше похоже на историзм... И "светило" с "девицами" - вполне себе современные слова. Впрочем, спросите у авторов теста, бог знает, что они там себе понапридумывали...

Comment: ДнЕвное светило - архаичный фразеологизм http://getword.ru/ru/slovari.php?topic=%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5&table=fedDSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Татьяна, точный ответ по историзмам: 
клавикордах, грош, барщину, унтер-офицеров. 
Все эти слова вышли из употребления в связи с уходом в историю данных предметов, званий. Ответ проверен лично на экзамене  по фонетике и лексикологии.

Comment: А источник сего сакрального знания не подскажете?

Comment: У меня недавно на сессии такой вопрос был) Сами далеко не с первой попытки подобрали нужные слова)) А вот с архаизмами так ничего и не получилось, перебрали все варианты

Comment: Источник-человеческий мозг

Comment: Здесь не принято ссылаться на непроверяемые источники.

Answer (score 2):

Историзмы: на клавикордах; городничий; барщину; унтер-офицеров.

Архаизмы: девицам; (*сызнова* — словари не считают это слово устаревшим, лишь просторечным/разговорным); цирюльник; ветрило.

Ваши ошибки:

1. *Грош* в данном контексте является частью фразеологизма *за грош удавится*, его собственное лексическое значение несколько затушевано, и его неправильно рассматривать как отдельную лексему.
2. *Светило* словари не считают устаревшим словом, оно просто из высокого регистра.

Comment: такой вариант тоже не подошёл(

Comment: @Татьяна так дело не в том, что подошло, а в том, какой ответ убедительно обоснован...

Comment: @Татьяна  Дайте уже ссылку на источник. А то подбирать коды к замку не слишком интересно.